Can I make a docker container copy its content out right before starting?
I have a docker-composer file and a Dockerfile for angular project, but it only works, when the node packages are already installed.
As node packages are excluded of the git repo, when someone clones it and tries to start it, it always fails. Dockerfile runs, it runs the command "npm install", but the node_modules directory is created only inside the container and when the container starts, the volume overrides the container's content, so the node_modules directory gets removed.
I have a workaround for that, I run a conteiner in interactive (docker run -it --name temp-container angular-image bash), run the npm install manually inside that container, then I exit the container and run "docker cp temp-container:/home/node/node_modules ./".
So I'm not interested in workarounds, I want to know, if there is any solution for this to install dependencies with npm inside the container for the first time it's built and copy the node_modules out from the container automatically when it's up.
Here's the docker-compose.yml (dummy version) and the Dockerfile:
version: '3'

services:
  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: 'angular'
    container_name: angular
    networks:
      - docker_infra
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node
    command: 'npm start'
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.angular.rule=(Host(`angular.lh`))"
      - "traefik.http.routers.angular.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.angular.loadbalancer.server.port=4200"
      - "traefik.docker.network=docker_infra"
    restart: unless-stopped
networks:
  docker_infra_infra:
    external: true

FROM node:20.9.0

ENV NODE_VERSION 20.9.0

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

WORKDIR /home/node
COPY . /home/node/

RUN npm install

I need to copy all the other content into the container, otherwise npm tells, it's not an angular project. I have the package.json, as it's included by the git repo.

As you note, the volumes: block is hiding the everything in the image, including its node_modules directory.  This isn't usually a best practice: since all of the code you're running comes from the host system, what you're running completely depends on what's on the local system, and you've reintroduced a substantial part of the "works on my system" problem that Docker usually tries to avoid.
Most of the options you show in the Compose file can be deleted, and I might reduce this to just
version: '3.8'
services:
  node:
    build: .
    labels: { traefik: things }
    restart: unless-stopped

In the Dockerfile, remember to include the CMD the image runs.  It's often helpful to separately COPY the package*.json files and RUN npm install, which will save time if you rebuild the image.
FROM node:20.9.0  # consider a less specific version

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

WORKDIR /home/node

# install library dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# copy in the rest of the application
COPY ./ ./  # make sure `node_modules` is in `.dockerignore`

CMD ["npm", "start"]


You may get recommendations to add a second volume to hold the node_modules tree, exploiting a Docker misfeature that copies content from the image into volumes.  This will cause Docker to actively ignore changes in the package.json file, and again the libraries you're running depend on what's in the local copy of the Docker volume and not anything reproducible.

Thank you! I know, docker is built for working with content from the host machine, but it also offers you the possibility to install all required developer tools ONLY in the container, so you don't have to keep any of them on the host machine. All you need, is docker. That's why I thought it's maybe possible to resolve that problem. Still I can do that workaround with a temporary container so docker still does its job, but I thought maybe someone could help. Thanks for the help! The check mark is deserved though.

But still... I thought it on... volumes are mirrored two way. If the container is already running and I remove a directory INSIDE the container, it will be removed from the host machine too via volumes. Of course that's not the recommended way to get rid of any files, but it's possible. So inside the volumes docker CAN operate with any content there and back between host macine and container.
